# Azure Recovery Services Vault - Copied Stored Permanently?

Tags: backup, azure, virtual-machines, recovery-services

I created a **recovery services vault** in Azure to back up a few **Azure VM's**. I've been performing **daily backups** of the VM's but the VM's are ***no longer needed***. I see settings for **weekly/monthly/yearly retention policies** for the recovery services vault. I'd like to **delete the VM's** to cut back on costs but I want to **store backup copies permanently** in case this project picks up in again in the future.

Are the **monthly/yearly retention policies** my only method for storing these VM's backups for an extended period of time/permanently, or if I leave these specific settings unconfigured will the recovery services vault store the backups permanently? Clarification or suggestions on storing VM backups in Azure long term would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default retention of backups is 30 days if you don't set anything up. Azure Backup allows for retention between 7 and 9999 days, there is not an option for permanent retention.